# Typescript this in nested object function

Tags: javascript, typescript, this

I have the following example, and I want to access `foo` variable within the function `a` of my object `test`.

```
class bar {
    private foo: string = "foobar";

    constructor() { /* ... Implementation ... */ }

    fncA(): this {
        // ... implementation 
        console.log(this.foo); // this is working as expected: "foobar"
        const test = {
            "a": function() {
                // ... implementation
            },
            "b": function() {
                console.log(this.foo); // TypeError: this.foo is undefined
            }
        };
        return this;
    }
}
```

> TypeError: this.foo is undefined

In my opinion these are some binding problems of the `this` variable, but I have no idea to solve this issue the right way.

I appreciate any help, thanks in advance.

Comment: Use an arrow function to keep `this` the same inside a function as outside it. `a: () => {`, `b: () => {`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In this particular case, you could make your functions in the `test` object [arrow functions](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Functions/Arrow_functions), so they *close over* `this` rather than having `this` set by how they're called:

```
class bar {
    private foo: string = "foobar";

    constructor() { /* ... Implementation ... */ }

    fncA(): this {
        // ... implementation 
        console.log(this.foo); // this is working as expected: "foobar"
        const test = {
            "a": () => {                // ***
                // ... implementation
            },
            "b": () => {                // ***
                console.log(this.foo);
            }
        };
        return this;
    }
}
```

*(Note that that fixes the TypeScript error about `this.foo`, but nothing ever* uses *the `test` object for anything in that code.)*

---

Side note: The overwhelming convention in JavaScript and TypeScript is that you capitalize the names of constructor functions. So `class Bar`, rather than `class bar`.